# accept-charset attribute in html form

Tags: html, http-headers

[The accept-charset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp) attribute specifies the character encodings that are to be used for the form submission . This attribute overrides the default encoding of html page specified in the header field of page while encoding the form submission data. How does the server know which encoding is used to encode the form submitted data? Does any request header are sent by browser to specify type of encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML5 suggests this as a form input value:](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#attr-fe-name)

> _charset_
>
> This value, if used as the name of a Hidden control with no value attribute, is automatically given a value during submission consisting
>   of the submission character encoding.

A quick test seems to indicate that it's pretty well supported in browsers at least back to IE7.